# How to display an image on an aspx page from a usercontrol without it taking up the whole page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, user-controls

I am new to this. The code below is what I have in my usercontrol, but when I insert it into an .aspx page the image takes over the whole page and removes other existing controls. How can I display the image including the graphics(g) within the div designated to the usercontrol in the .aspx page, without it removing all the other controls? Thanks

DisplayImage.aspx (User Control)

```
Bitmap BitMapImage= new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("image1.Png"));
Graphics g= Graphics.FromImage(BitMapImage); 
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

g.DrawString( "GREAT", new Font("Calibri", 18,FontStyle.Bold ), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point( 175, 300 ) );

Response.ContentType="image/Png"; 
BitMapImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the image as a separate URL. You reference the image URL from the HTML generated by your aspx page, but the image itself is generated in response to a different HTTP request.

Comment: so basically do I have to store it first into a folder then read it from there?

Comment: the image doesn't have to be a physical file; you can dynamically generate it from an aspx file -- just reference the image-generating aspx file from your HTML using an `<img>` tag.

Comment: I had to make it an ashx file first, but ye it works great thanks

Comment: Yes, an ashx HttpHandler is the preferred approach. You can make it work with an aspx too, but it's not as clean.

Answer (score 1):

According to RickNZ's answer, try this logic:

First. assume you want to show all images in DisplayImage.aspx page, the code should like:

```
img src="Img.aspx?id=xx"/>
```

Second. put above code into Img.aspx page.